# Mechanism binding click event handler to massive <td> elements

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a big `HTML` table which has same-data-coloring feature by user's double-clicking on a certain cell, the table has over 8000 cells and cells will be increased.
At this point, I thought it could be a burdened working to a web-browser.
Yes, I want to know the in-depth mechanism and burdening degree of attaching event-handler to massive `<td>` elements.

The code:

```
<script>
   var otable = document.getElementById("htbl_drawresult");
   var irIndex = 0;
   var icIndex = 0;
   var sintxt = "";

    for(var i = 1; i < otable.rows.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < otable.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
        {
            otable.rows[i].cells[j].ondblclick = function()
            {
                irIndex = this.parentElement.rowIndex;
                icIndex = this.cellIndex+1;
                sintxt = this.innerText;                    
                f_colorcell(sintxt, otable);
            };
        }
    }

    function f_colorcell(stxt, otbl){
        var irow = otbl.rows.length;
        var icol = otbl.rows[1].cells.length;
        var i,j=0;

        for(i=1; i<irow; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<icol; j++)
            {
               if (otbl.rows[i].cells[j].innerText == stxt){
                   otbl.rows[i].cells[j].style.background=\"red\";
               }
            }
        }
    }        
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just summarising @[C.RaysOfTheSun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10386872/c-raysofthesun)'s answer:

Yes, it would be *burdensome* to attach an event each on every cell of the table.

However, you could structure your HTML in such a way that the cells (`TD`s) can each be uniquely identified. And when events propagate from a target to an ancestor (`TABLE` element for instance) where a listener is **commonly** attached, it's simple to determine the actual target in the listener.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main, false);

function main() {
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")[0];

  table.addEventListener("dblclick", handleDoubleClickOnTable, false);
}

function handleDoubleClickOnTable( /* event => */ e) {

  var target = e.target;
  var row, column;
  var rowNumber, columnNumber;

  if ("TD" !== target.tagName) {
    return;
  }

  row = target.parentNode;
  column = target;

  rowNumber = row.dataset.rowNumber;
  columnNumber = column.dataset.columnNumber;

  alert(`You clicked on ( row[ ${ rowNumber } ], column[ ${ columnNumber } ] )`);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dee2e6;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- Sample 3 x 3 table -->
<table>
  <tr data-row-number="1">
    <td data-column-number="1">( 1, 1 )</td>
    <td data-column-number="2">( 1, 2 )</td>
    <td data-column-number="3">( 1, 3 )</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row-number="2">
    <td data-column-number="1">( 2, 1 )</td>
    <td data-column-number="2">( 2, 2 )</td>
    <td data-column-number="3">( 2, 3 )</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row-number="3">
    <td data-column-number="1">( 3, 1 )</td>
    <td data-column-number="2">( 3, 2 )</td>
    <td data-column-number="3">( 3, 3 )</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth re-touching, very helpfull, thanks :-)

Comment: You're welcome :-)

If you find the answer useful, then you may effectively indicate so by upvoting it and/or accepting it as an answer. That way others can benefit from your evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about assigning an event handler for the cells (`<td>`) inside your table, you can do it in two ways:

### 1. Event Propagation

- A shorter and much simpler way of doing it. You can assign an event handler to the parent (the `<table>` element itself) and everything inside it will have the event handler as well. Simply put, what the parent gets, the child will also get.

  - Recommended if you don't need a specific thing to happen when a given element is clicked. Although, you can always narrow things down by utilizing [Event.Target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
  - In the example below, I have assigned a `click` event listener to the table (parent) so that when you click on anything inside it, an alert saying "You clicked on a cell and it had the value of [cell value]" will show up
  - Here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/YJrEKm) for event propagation.
  - ```js
    window.onload = ()=>{
      // get our table
      let tb = document.getElementById('main-table');
      // assign a click event to it
      tb.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        alert(`You clciked on a cell and it had the value of ${e.target.innerHTML}`)
      })
    }
    ```

    ```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <table class="table" id="main-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    ```

### 2. Manually assigning a specific event handler to each element

- You can always set an event handler for each cell (`<td>`) specifically by grabbing them using JavaScript's built-in functions (i.e. [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), etc...) then assigning a function to be called on a specific event using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

  - **Not recommended** for a large collection of elements.
  - You can play around with the snippet below [here](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/OBxOOp) :)
  - ```js
    window.onload = ()=>{
      // get our table
      let table = document.getElementById('main-table');
      // get all the cells in the table element above
      let tableCells = table.querySelectorAll('td');
      // assign an event listener to each cell <td> element inside that table specifically
      for(let i = 0; i < tableCells.length; i++){
        tableCells[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
          alert(`You clicked on cell index ${i} and it had the value of ${this.innerHTML}`);
        })
      } 
    }
    ```

    ```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <table class="table" id="main-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    ```

:)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add click event listeners, you can use jQuery. You can use this for any HTML element.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#result").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
$("#button").dblclick(function() {
  $("#result").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  border: .5px solid black;
}
#button {
  background-color: white;
}
#result {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

If you click the <code>div</code> once, the square will turn yellow.<br>
If you double click the <code>div</code>, the square will turn red.<br>
CM = Click Me
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td id="button">CM</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Don't suggest jQuery Answers if the op doesn't mention it.